# How to cancel all subscriptions inside UseEffect in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error - Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Here's my useEffect hook, I used a ref called mounted to check if the component has unmounted or not but I am still getting the error when the component unmounts. (It takes about a minute for the error to show up).

```
    useEffect(() => {
            if(mounted.current){
                if(mincounter === 0 && hrcounter > 0){ 
                    setHrcounter(hrcounter - 1);
                    setMincounter(60);
                    mincounter > 0 && setTimeout(() => setMincounter(mincounter - 1) , 1000*60)
                }else if (mincounter === 0 && hrcounter === 0){
                    submitHandler()
                }else{
                    mincounter > 0 && setTimeout(() => setMincounter(mincounter - 1) , 1000*60)
                }
            }
        return () => {
            mounted.current = false
            console.log('info tab unmounting', mounted.current);
        }
    }, [mincounter, hrcounter, submitHandler,setHrcounter,setMincounter]);
```

TIA

Comment: Also in your code, remove the setState functions from the  dependencies array (in useEffect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the error because your code is calling `setMincounter` in a timeout callback after the component is unmounted. Move your unmounted check inside the timeout callback.

Another problem in your code is that you're setting `mounted.current` to `false` on any cleanup, not just unmounts. This means the effect callback would only run once and then short-circuit on the if condition every time. Let's instead clean up by replacing our potentially unsafe callback with a no-op. Alternatively you could clean up by canceling the timeouts.

Here's the fixed code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let safeSetMincounter = setMinCounter;
    if(mincounter === 0 && hrcounter > 0){ 
    setHrcounter(hrcounter - 1);
        setMincounter(60);
        mincounter > 0 && setTimeout(() => safeSetMincounter(mincounter - 1), 1000*60)
    }else if (mincounter === 0 && hrcounter === 0){
        submitHandler()
    }else{
        mincounter > 0 && setTimeout(() => safeSetMincounter(mincounter - 1), 1000*60)
    }
    return () => void (safeSetMincounter = () => undefined);
}, [mincounter, hrcounter, submitHandler,setHrcounter,setMincounter]);
```

There's still a number of other problems in the code but they're off-topic for this question.

Comment: I am kinda new to React If you don't mind can you point out the other problems?

Comment: I don't mind at all.

1. If submitHandler changes, the timeout is restarted. You can omit it from deps if you pass it by reference. `const submitHandlerRef = useRef(submitHandler); submitHandlerRef.current = submitHandler` and inside your effect call `submitHandlerRef.current()`.

2. Your effect callback handles both setting up the clock and handling the changes in time values. The two should be separate `useEffect`s. Currently your code relies on this hackiness but if you refactor it with `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` instead you can achieve a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
   const [subscriptions, setSubscriptions] = useState([]);
```

I usually store all my subscriptions on my component state and then call them when component will be un mounted (in the cleanup of useEffect hook)

Like this:

```
   useEffect(() => {
      const subscription1 = ...
      const subscription2 = ...
      // When you create subscriptions, just store them on state
      setSubscriptions([...subscriptions, subscription1, subscription2]);

      // Cleanup (Detach subscriptions)
      return () => subscriptions.forEach(subscription => subscription)

   },[])
```